# executing print in spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Let's suppose I have a very basic spark streaming application which reads 100 records of data from kafka, run one map step and then call stream.print(5) in each intervall. Everything is running fine. Spark prints 5 records in each intervall. My question is: does the print function makes spark calculate the map step on all 100 records or only on the 5 I am asking for?
I just want to be sure that spark executes all the steps on all the data because I am running some performance tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark will run the `map` stage on entire `DStream`. The fact that you only print 5 records is because only they are consumed from the iterator, but rest assure all data will pass the transformation.